# Convert varchar column to date in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I need to perform a query to a model that has column datetime saved in character varying here is my query

```
const _from = new Date(from).getTime();
Model.findAll({where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('datetime', Sequelize.col('start')), '>=', _from)})
```

with the above query this is the response: `function datetime(character varying) does not exist`

I have also try the following:

```
const _from = new Date(from);
Model.findAll({where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('date', Sequelize.col('start')), '>=', from)})
```

and with the above query this is the response: `date/time field value out of range: 1495828800000`

this is a screenshot of the columns in the table, I'm using postgress and Sequelize in Nodejs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

For sequelize >= 4.12.0

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const _from = new Date(from).getTime();
Model.findAll({where: { start : {[Op.gte]: _from}})
```

For sequelize < 4.12.0 :

```
const _from = new Date(from).getTime();
Model.findAll({where: { start : {$gte: _from}})
```

Just by curiosity, why you store a date in a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Which version use Sequelize.Op? if I try that I get `Cannot read property 'gte' of undefined` because `Op` is undefined, I'm using version 3.23, Varchar datatype for dates was like that before I tried to do anything there.